# Roles of the objects in MVC

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

I've written a simple website using PHP, and the code is getting a little out of hand, so I thought I'd rewrite it using MVC. I do however have a few questions that I can't find answers to (not even on SO).

**This is what I've learnt so far:**

- The thing that ties everything together is the front controller,
  index.php
- The front controller uses the URL to instantiate a model, controller
  and view

**Now on to the questions:**

- Every view example that I found retrieves a short HTML snippet (i.e.
  a table) from the model. Where does the full HTML page get generated?
  Is this the responsibility of the front controller, to insert the
  table in a template?
- My current start page have several independent lists (let's say book
  titles in one, and categories in another) dynamically generated. How
  would I achieve this, when MVC (if I've understood it correctly) only
  allows me to use one controller (and thus, one model) at the same
  time? Is it possible to use multiple view and insert them in to the
  HTML template, i.e. the menu is retrieved from CategoryListView and
  the book info table is retrieved from BookListView?

Comment: *"Every view example that I found retrieves a short HTML snippet (i.e. a table) from the model"* - are you sure it wasn't given by the controller? A controller can make use of more than 1 model, and a model can make use of another model through relationships.

Comment: The view fetches data from the model, which has been configured by the controller. [This](https://r.je/mvc-php-front-controller.html) is the site I've mostly learnt from. The full code is available just above the _Conclusion_ headline.

Comment: imo, The `front controller` decodes the URL (routing) and decides which controller to run. It is the controller that decides which models and views it wants to use. Very simplified.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but there's a 1:1:1 mapping of every model, view and controller. Thus, if the front controller determines which controller to use, the controller doesn't have anything to say about it.

Comment: Oh. Every view example I've found has used exactly one model (which used exactly one controller). As for the HTML rendering. Is that up to each and every view to render the full code (<!DOCTYPE html><html>...</html>) or is this handled by front controller, which fetches snippets form the views? There's going to be very much repeated code if every view must construct it's own HTML.